# AppStore - App status is ready for sale, but not in app store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Status of app ready for sale still 9 June..

Like in there https://discussions.apple.com/message/8147141

App link : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yupek-mebel/id884771427?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: i have the same issue when was the problem solved bro ...

Comment: where can i find that app release date thing

Comment: but for me the available date is 10th oct,2014 only

Comment: @seenu In my case solution was only changing date. Also i writed message to apple. Try to ask they. They answering, in 10 days.

Comment: Apple should simply change "Ready for Sale" status only after app is live on the app store. Because most of the beginner developer is getting mislead by this behaviour.

Comment: Yess!! it did it. after that head to: App Information > Additional Information > View on App Store (Just to heighlight one of the comments below, by @Kash)

Answer (score 91):

After your app status changes to *'Ready for Sale'* you will get official mail from Apple. The mail itself states that it **might take 24 hours before your App is available on AppStore.** 
If it takes more than days then contact Apple.

Refer below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is there any way to know when the app is indeed in the store (besides keep accessing every hour) ?

Comment: what about updates to an existing app? does it also take 24 hours? The email does not say this for updates.

Answer (score 76):

You have to go to the "Pricing" menu. Even if the availability date is in the past, sometimes you have to set it again for today's date. Apple doesn't tell you to do this, but I found that the app goes live after resetting the dates again, especially if there's been app rejections in the past. I guess it messes up with the dates. Looks like sometimes if you do nothing and just follow the instructions, the app will never go live.

Comment: This is a live saver! Apple seems to have a bug and after waiting for **60h** to see my app update (that was Ready For Sale) in store, I changed the pricing plan (from 0 to 0 starting today) and after 30 min my update was live. Thanks!

Comment: If I change the availability date do I have through go through the review process again?

Comment: Another useful thing here would be using the iTunes Connect management mobile app - sometimes you can get better notifications this way on your app's status.

Comment: VERY much appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Did *NOT* worked for us. It's been now 5 hours since we did this

Comment: Yess!! it did it. after that head to: App Information > Additional Information > View on App Store

Comment: I had the same issue (20 hours delay). I changed a letter of the promotional text, then save it, rolled back the change and saved it again. In 5 minutes it was available.

Comment: Just had the issue as well. Very helpful you had this fix posted here. Thanks.

Comment: The "Plan a Price Change" worked for us too, thank you!

Comment: eyal_katz can't reset time, it's locked. any idea?

Answer (score 31):

I thought I will post my answer as I recently got into a similar issue (as of **September 2019**). The App is free for all users in all countries.

For me, after I received a confirmation email from Apple saying that my app is ready for sale (the email did not mention any 24 hours waiting period), I could not find my App in the App Store.

The link to view the App in the App Store in the iTunes Connect (under the App Information section at the bottom page) was broken.

After reading your comments in this thread, I went to the Pricing and Availability section of the App and edited the pricing plan again to be 0 GBP and start date **Today** and finish date **No Finish Date**.

Then, I **unchecked** the countries the App is available on and **checked** them all again and hit **Save**.

The App became immediately available in the App store. The link in the App information section was directing me to the App Store and no longer broken.

I hope this will help anyone who is having similar issues lately (getting a confirmation email that the App is ready for sale but cannot find it in the App Store).

Comment: You saved me from heart attack. I thought it'll not take more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Please note we need to save after unchecking. Then check and save again.

Comment: This is it. Country list needs to be unchecked and checked again.

Comment: Thanks this solved it for me, had to save after uncheck also. Got fixed after about 30 minutes. Then it got available on my M1 Mac as well

Answer (score 13):

It takes *up to* 24 hours before its available in each and every (country wise) app store. If you have waited more than that, and still have problems, contact Apple.

Comment: @alashow It has been 16 days since they approve or since you submit?

Comment: @alashow then there is something wrong! it shouldn't take that long for URL.

Answer (score 13):

After 48 hours of the still not being updated I removed the app from sale on Pricing and Availability.

Then I waited 1 hour.

Then I ticked All Territories Selected again.

After the app came available for download again the version number was updated.

Comment: This worked. But I didn't wait 1 hour. I changed it back right away and the version on the App Store was updated right away.

Comment: Did *NOT* worked for us. It's been now 5 hours since we did this.

Comment: Checked "Remove from sale", saved, waited 1min, checked all the countries back again, save, and voilá!

Comment: worked for me, I just changed Territories and clicked on save , within 30 minutes it was available . No need to Remove from sale

Answer (score 4):

I published an update to my app yesterday noon(I have selected Manual release instead of Automatic) and Today early morning App store review was completed and after I release the build manually, the App shows Ready for sale in iTunesConect immediately. After 45mins I got the update on the App store.

Answer (score 4):

I had "ready for sale" status for 1 week and app still wasn't visible in store.
I "changed" the pricing (from free to free starting today) like KlimczakM suggested in one of comments above. Also, I changed promotional text and saved changes. After less than half of hour app was in the store.

Answer (score 2):

We published it today after having 'Release this version'. It took 15 minutes to show on the App Store.

This is due to App Store will sync the data across servers.

Answer (score 2):

you must change Territory and click on save, after one minute your app will be available. No need to Remove from sale

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to provide your contact info, bank info, and tax info in this page so it will allow your last release on App Store:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/6.0

Answer (score 1):

go to this section and add price if you don't want price for this app add price 0.00 and then within 20 mins your app was seen on app store thanks me later!! [image]