# Ready for sale app cannot be found without iTunes connect

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I have uploaded an app to apple app store, its status shows Ready for sale, and I can view it from itunes connect with View on App store, but when I search for it, I can't find it.

It should available for all territories, so any account from any country should be fine.

Also, when I viewed it through iTunes, I purchased it, and on my iPhone it appears on my Purchases list, when I click to show app info it keeps loading forever.

what is going on?

Comment: how much time before  you upload app o@Masashi

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27936822/5997339,   http://stackoverflow.com/a/30736851/5997339

Comment: My latest update to 3 days to be available and still some user are reporting that they get the old version. So there might be some issue at this moment with releasing app. My advice is wait 48 hours (just to make sure) and then contact Apple.

Comment: I uploaded it April 2nd, and on April 4th they sent me that is it Ready for sale and it can take up to 24 hours.

Though till now I can't find it on app store by searching, I am only able to see it through view on app store option from iTunes connect.

Comment: @VinodKumar please check my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a simple trick - go back to app description, make a simple edition and save. I tried it after waiting more than 24 hours and in AppStore there was still available the old version of my app. After that, the new app's version became visible within an hour.

Comment: I will try it and see, I edited pricing and sat it again to today's date, will wait and see what happens.

Comment: @Masashi If I edit the pricing/ change description/ remove the app from sale will I have to go through the review process again? I have waiting for around 3 hours now and iTunes is still showing the old update. However it is showing Updated: Nov 06, 2017 on the left side which is actually todays date!

Comment: @Mahbub Morshed Prottoy : No, I just did that on my app. You dont have to go through the whole process again.

Answer (score 0):

Check build version for your app and testing device. If app version is higher, than test device, it may be not visible on AppStore

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue I upload the new version of the app with the help of iTunesConnect but the app store does not show my new version.
when I upload the app into iTunes I upload the app version 1.06 but due to some error upload is invalid so again I fix the minor error and upload again but this time but not opening again the version (i have already open iTunes so I just upload the new build but not create the new version into iTunes.)

so I click the new version again on the iTunes connect account and set also the same version 1.0.7 and set the same version on the app and change the build number and upload again from Xcode into iTunes and then save and click to submit the after one-day reviewing time my new version uploaded on the app store.